# Extracting a numerical value without class id in html using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, text-parsing

I am looking to extract the value of "Estimated zip code population in 2015" from the city-data website for a certain region (http://www.city-data.com/zips/17033.html). I used beautifulsoup to extract the value, but couldn't suceed.

The problem is because there is no class id associated with it. So, I used "soup.find(text=re.compile("^Estimated zip code population in 2015"))" but it only returns the text and not the numerical value which is "17,649".

Please find my code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.city-data.com/zips/17033.html') as 
response:
    html = response.read()
    print("html", html)


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
population=soup.find(text=re.compile("^Estimated zip code population in 2015"))
print(population)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have lxml library installed in your machine then there is a solution for you. Regex will not be necessary for that. Let me know.

Comment: Hi Shahin,  Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I have it installed. I followed what one of the other members suggested and I am getting the output. But I am interested in exploring how lxml works. Please can you let me know how to use lxml for this?

Answer (score 0):

Find your element as a `b` tag and find it's `next_sibling` to get the text that you want.

Example:

```
population = soup.find("b", text=re.compile("^Estimated zip code population in 2015"))
print population.get_text(), population.next_sibling
```

Outputs:

> Estimated zip code population in 2015:  17,649

Comment: Zroq,Thanks a lot, it worked. I really appreciate it.